# What is the query for retrieving a list of linked objects in a sqlite database with multiple tables?

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite, cursor, multiple-tables

I have made a sqlite database with the following tables:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_CITY+"("
            +KEY_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
            +KEY_CITY+" TEXT, "+KEY_COUNTRY+" TEXT)");
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_DIARY+"("
            +KEY_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
            +KEY_DATE+" TEXT, "+KEY_STORY+" TEXT)");
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_CITY_DIARY+"("
            +KEY_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
            +KEY_CITY_ID+" TEXT, "+KEY_DIARY_ID+" TEXT)");
}
```

Now I want to retrieve a list of all the diary entries that belong to a certain city (e.g. Barcelona contains 3 diary entries and Rome 5, but I only want a list of the 3 belonging to Barcelona).
I made a method for this, but I'm not sure what the query should be.

```
    public List<Diary> getDiariesByCity(String city_name){
    List<Diary>diaries=new ArrayList<Diary>();
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor curs=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_DIARY........,
            new String[]{city_name});
    if(curs.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            Diary diary=new Diary();
            diary.setId(curs.getInt(curs.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID)));
            diary.setDate(curs.getString(curs.getColumnIndex(KEY_DATE)));
            diary.setStory(curs.getString(curs.getColumnIndex(KEY_STORY)));
            diaries.add(diary);
        }while(curs.moveToNext());
    }return diaries;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use INNER JOIN like this:

```
Cursor curs=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " +  TABLE_CITY_DIARY + 
+ " INNER JOIN " + TABLE_CITY + " ON " + TABLE_CITY_DIARY + "." + KEY_CITY_ID + "=" + TABLE_CITY + "." + KEY_ID 
+ " INNER JOIN " + TABLE_DIARY + " ON " + TABLE_CITY_DIARY + "." + KEY_DIARY_ID + "=" + TABLE_DIARY + "." + KEY_ID 
+ " WHERE " +  TABLE_CITY + "." + KEY_CITY + "=?", new String[]{city_name});
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about INNER JOIN yet, but it works indeed. Only little error is that KEY_COUNTRY in the last argument should be KEY_CITY.